# Linux usando no travis

Tags: travis-ci

Então estou querendo adicionar meu projeto no travis, notei que ele faz uso de Ubuntu, queria saber se existe alguma forma de compilar meu projeto em CentOS e Ubuntu usando travis ?

Answer (score 1):

Não. Como a própria documentação diz, esta disponível apenas Ubuntu e OS X, sendo o OS X utilizado apenas para as builds de Objective-C.

Do item *CI environment OS*:

> Travis CI virtual machines are based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition 64 bit, with the exception of Objective-C builds, which runs on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Link para documentação:

[Travis CI: The Build Environment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/)

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer Vinicius.

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer isso através de uma solução de contorno: Colocar um virtualizador dentro da virtualização. Se você adicionar um container Docker no Travis será possível rodar o teu build dentro de qualquer SO. O arquivo *.travis.yml* ficaria semelhante ao arquivo abaixo:

```
sudo: required
env:
  matrix:
  - OS_TYPE=centos OS_VERSION=6
  - OS_TYPE=centos OS_VERSION=7

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -s devicemapper"' | sudo tee /etc/default/docker > /dev/null
  - sudo service docker restart
  - sleep 5
  - sudo docker pull centos:centos${OS_VERSION}

script:
 # Run tests in Container
- tests/setup_tests.sh ${OS_VERSION}
```

Traduzindo, você estaria iniciando o serviço do Docker, baixando a imagem do CentOS na versão desejada e rodando o build ou testes no container Docker do CentOS.

**Referências**: https://djw8605.github.io/2016/05/03/building-centos-packages-on-travisci/